# Insert children into Angular Dart Component (shadow root)

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angularjs-ng-transclude, shadow-dom

Let's say I have a component:

```dart
@Component(selector: 'app-menu', 
    templateUrl: '.../menu.html', 
    cssUrl: const ['.../menu.css'], 
    publishAs: 'Menu')
class MenuComponent {

  bool showOptions = true;
  void toggleOptions() {
    showOptions = !showOptions;
  }
}
```

And a view for the component:

```dart
<div class="menu" ng-click="Menu.toggleOptions()">
  <span icon="drawer"></span>
  <ul ng-show="Menu.showOptions" class="options">
    <!-- I want put content here -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Finally, the usage (theoretically):

```dart
<app-menu>
  <menu-item>Remove</menu-item>
</app-menu>
```

After running the program I'd like to see `<menu-item>Remove</menu-item>` inside shadow root where I've put `<!-- I want put content here -->`. I've read that there were a `<content />` component but it isn't working like that (nothing happened, I've seen only `<output/>` element). Also I've tried ng-transclude directive with no success.

Can someone help me and point the right way to do this?

Comment: "I've read that there were a <content /> component" the content tag is not a component (ie something from angular) but is defined by the shadow DOM spec. This is the place where your original "light DOM" get inserted. Check http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/ for more info. There is also a Google Maps example that has been added to Angular recently that you can look. Note that the content tag will work as expected even if your component does not use shadowDom ("useShadowDom: false" option).

Answer (score 0):

Well,
After some tests and looking into Angular Dart tutorials I've found a solution.
My example above isn't actually accurate. I've used an `<li>` element instead of `<menu-item>`. Somehow, when I changed "li" to "span" it just started working. Perhaps DOM parser have rejected "li" element before it has been attached into correct structure inside shadow root tree. I don't really know. 
However right after the change it started working.

Comment: `<ul>` only allows `<li>`, `<ol>`, `<ul>` als children. This is the reason why `<content>` didn't work otherwise this is exactly what the `<content>` tag is for.

Comment: It left me (`li` tag) from previous structure. There was ul > li as a menu and I've replaced it witch components but I did not changed li to `<menu-item/>`. Stupid mistake :)